# Como ordenar bancos de dados em ordem alfabética sem que os caracteres com acento fiquem fora de ordem

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou criando um banco de dados no MySql e quero colocar algumas informações em ordem alfabética. O problema é que, quando adiciono o filtro de ordem alfabética crescente, as palavras que começam em caracteres acentuados aparecem por último. Por exemplo: Se eu coloco as entradas "Água", "Alarme" e "Azedo', a ordem fica "Alarme", "Azedo" e "Água".

Quero que a ordem alfabética seja mantida, independente de o caractere ter ou não acentuação.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link: https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/ignorando-letras-maiusculas-minusculas-acentos-e-c/

Comment: Nossa, eu esqueci de avisar. Adiciona teu comentário como resposta, por gentileza